# How to get rule id with respect to customer group id

Tags: magento2, collection, shopping-cart-price-rules, customer-group, price-rules

```
class CouponCode extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{


  protected $_customerSession;

  protected $_customerGroupCollection;


  public function __construct(
  \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
  \Magento\Customer\Model\Group $customerGroupCollection,
  \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context) 
  {

    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_customerGroupCollection = $customerGroupCollection;
    parent::__construct($context);
  }

    public function getCouponCodes()
    {


        $currentGroupId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId(); //Get customer group Id , you have already this so directly get name
        $collection = $this->_customerGroupCollection->load($currentGroupId); 


        return $collection->getCustomerGroupCode();//Get group name

    }
```

> 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your block constructor inject

```
\Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\CollectionFactory $salesRuleCollectionFactory,
```

and then filter the sales rules collection by customer group id

```
$_salesRulecollectionByCustomerGroup = $this->_salesRuleCollectionFactory->create()->addCustomerGroupFilter($currentGroupId);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response,but after injecting this dependency ,nothing is shown on the screen, 
**addAttributeInConditionFilteraddCustomerGroupFilter** do you think this line is properly defined?

Comment: to debug this, you can enable the developer mode to print the error on the screen or check the logs....BTW check your Magento version to confirm whether this method is present in this file \Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\Collection

Comment: Yes ,there are two method found in the file \Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\Collection
'public function addAttributeInConditionFilter($attributeCode)'
'public function addCustomerGroupFilter($customerGroupId)'
but from which one of above we have to used?for my solution and in which way?

Comment: Thanks alot,addCustomerGroupFilter($customerGroupId) function work for me

Comment: Can you have any idea about this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/305896/magento-2add-another-new-custom-mini-cart

Answer (score 2):

Please add this code in your file. Youo will get what you want

```
$currentGroupId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId(); 
    $_salesRulecollectionByCustomerGroup = $this->_salesRuleCollectionFactory->create()->addCustomerGroupFilter($currentGroupId);
    $collection = $this->_customerGroupCollection->load($currentGroupId);
    $result=$_salesRulecollectionByCustomerGroup->getData();
    foreach ($result as $res) {
        print_r($res['rule_id']);

    }
```

And Customize it according to your code.