# Magento 2:Add another new Custom mini-cart?

Tags: addtocart, shopping-cart-price-rules, knockoutjs, mini-cart, modal-popup

I want to add new Minicart like shown in the following screenshot, using **KnockOut** Js, Give me some logic how can I cater to this problem[image]

Comment: The minibasket uses the dropdownDialog plugin so you can reuse that - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_dialog.html

Comment: Thanks Ben ,But will it also show count along with it like our normal Minicart?

Comment: Nope, the count comes from the minicart template file using knockout, search for `getCartParam('summary_count')` to find that, the getCartParam function is defined in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js:168` (dependant on your version of Magento.

I don't have time to provide a full answer sorry but hopefully that points you in the right direction.